# Apache > Setup Server Side Includes > OSX Snow Leopard > Still Not Working

Tags: apache, osx-snow-leopard, server-side-includes

I have researched this for about 2+ hours including 1+ hour of preparing this report (I must be a slow worker, considering I haven't slept in 24 hours :-P)

The virtual server side include works in Dreamweaver (except for image rendering), but does not work when I browse to the web page.

`<!--#include virtual="/partialHtml/businessResult.shtml" -->`

I realize that I have overridden far too many configuration settings (and if there's a simpler and more elegant way, perhaps just using a `.htaccess` file in `~/Sites/mysite.com/` then please also comment) ;-)

Starting from the top (1) `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

(2) `sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /Users/tidy/Sites/mysite.com>
    Options +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +Includes
    DirectoryIndex index.htm
    AllowOverride All
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
  </Directory>
  DocumentRoot /Users/tidy/Sites/mysite.com
  ServerName mysite.local
  ErrorLog "/Users/tidy/Sites/mysite.com/log/error_log"
  CustomLog "/Users/tidy/Sites/mysite.com/log/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

(3) `sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/users/tidy.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/tidy/Sites/">
  Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddType text/html .shtml
  AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</Directory>
```

(4) `sudo nano ~/Sites/mysite.com/.htaccess`

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
Options +Includes
XBitHack on
```

I also tried to use `XBitHack on` by doing `chmod +x ~/Sites/mysite.com/partialHtml/businessResult.html` and then including that file (apparently it makes `.html` file server side includes efficient, if you don't want to use `.shtml` files)

Obviously I'm doing a `sudo apachectl configtest` to make sure everything's okay.

I get a warning (that I've tried to get rid of) but the syntax is OK.

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using complexity.local for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

Then a `sudo apachectl restart`

Here is my most recent activity in `cat ~/Sites/mysite.com/log/access_log`

```
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:05 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:07 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:08 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:15 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:16 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:11:17 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3924
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:03 +0000] "GET /css/site.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3077
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:03 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 124223
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:03 +0000] "GET /img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 19217
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:04 +0000] "GET /img/searchFormGradient.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 501
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:04 +0000] "GET /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8777
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:04 +0000] "GET /img/headerGradient.png HTTP/1.1" 200 216
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:04 +0000] "GET /js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 31596
::1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /css/site.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /img/headerGradient.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2013:12:12:18 +0000] "GET /img/searchFormGradient.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

The `HTTP/1.1 304` code is `HTTP Error 304 - Not modified` which isn't an error, it's a signal from the server to the browser, that the current content hasn't changed since the last request.

As you can see from the `GET` requests, there's no sign of `/partialHtml/businessResult.shtml`

Here is my most recent activity in `cat ~/Sites/mysite.com/log/error_log`

```
[Tue Jan 08 11:24:49 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/tidy/Sites/mysite.com/favicon.ico
```

And after all of that... the Server Side Include mechanism is not working :-(

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution to my problem.

I was having the same problem with Server Side Includes on Windows 7, because I was under the false impression that **only** the included file has to have an `.shtml` extension.

Because the line:
`<!--#include file="partialHtml/businessResult.shtml" -->`

Was in a file called:
`index.html`

The server side include module was not pre-processing the file.

After I changed `index.html` to `index.shtml` the server side include module correctly 
pre-processed everything.

TL;DR - The file that includes a server side include has to have a .shtml extension.